# Why is this character transported into the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

Why does Eddie Brock come into the MCU in *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)?

It seems to be a plot hole, because

> Doctor Strange's spell brings everyone who knows Peter Parker is Spider-Man into the universe, but Eddie Brock has never known this. In the mid-credits scene, however, he is shown to have been transported into the MCU.

How did this happen?

Comment: [spoiler] In the mid-credit scene, the character is shown to be transported back (minus one part of his body, for no reason) to his universe. The visual effect is the same as the one used for other characters going back home.

Comment: Venom says the hive has "80 billion light-years of knowledge across universes" - I suppose we have to take him literally on the universes plural part.  Obviously he recognized spiderman when the universe switch happened. https://youtu.be/EOjufJgSUB8

Comment: Similar question from sister site: [In Spider-Man No Way Home, how did *anti-hero* come into this universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/116495/in-spider-man-no-way-home-how-did-anti-hero-come-into-this-universe)

Comment: @lucasbachmann no he didn't. the symbiote simply said "that guy" and licked the screen. Indicating that he wanted to rip Peter's head off just like he does to all criminals (because acc. to the news on the DB, Peter was a criminal).

Comment: Pretty simple this movie and the show Loki broke the barriers between multiple universes.  And Disney owns Marvel and Fox... I’m waiting for the Avengers and X-men versus Darth Vader.

Answer (score 23):

**Warning: this answer contains spoilers for both *Venom: Let There Be Carnage* and *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.**

Eddie's initial transference to the MCU seemingly occurred in the mid-credits scene of *Venom: Let There Be Carnage*.

Eddie is lying on a bed watching a soap opera on television, when the symbiote mentions that it has a past that Eddie doesn't know about, including "80 billion light-years of hive knowledge across universes".

It decides to give Eddie a taste of this knowledge, and just as that happens, there's a distortion effect around the room, and Eddie suddenly finds himself lying on a bed in a different room, where J. Jonah Jameson is on TV, reporting on the reveal of Spider-Man's secret identity.

Eddie then assumes his Venom form, walks over to the TV screen -- which is showing a close-up of an unmasked Spider-Man's (Tom Holland's) face -- and the symbiote says "That guy..." and licks the screen, possibly signifying some degree of recognition.

> SYMBIOTE: Oh, I love this show.
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Maximiliano’s feelings are not being validated.
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah, well, he never should’ve kept such an insane secret, man.
>
> SYMBIOTE: **We all have a past, Eddie.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What, are you… you hiding stuff from me?
>
> SYMBIOTE: **80 billion light-years of hive knowledge across universes would explode your tiny little brain.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What-what does that even mean, man?
>
> SYMBIOTE: **Well, let me give you a taste, then. Just the smallest fraction of the things we symbiotes have experienced.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Okay.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Ready, Eddie?
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Whoa. What’s happening?
>
> EDDIE BROCK: No, no, no, no. No, no, no, no, no.
>
> SYMBIOTE: What the hell is that?!
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Oh, that’s a… that-that’s just a towel. Where are we? Wh-What did you do?
>
> SYMBIOTE: It wasn’t me.
>
> J. JONAH JAMESON [on television]: Incredibly, this shocking revelation brought to life by yours truly has only raised…
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What? What-what... what is this?
>
> J. JONAH JAMESON [on television]: …of Peter Parker, aka Spider-Man, aka the Spider Menace. But rest assured, dear viewers, we here at The Daily Bugle will...
>
> SYMBIOTE: **That guy...**
>
> <sub>*Venom: Let There Be Carnage* (2021)</sub>

The implication of all this seems to be that the symbiote -- through a hive mind link with symbiotes in other universes -- had knowledge of the Peter Parker/Spider-Man of another universe, and that when it shared this knowledge with Eddie, both of them unwittingly became subject to the spell cast by Dr. Strange in *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

It's conceivable that the symbiote specifically knew about the [Tobey Maguire  version of Peter Parker/Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-96283)), via a hive mind link with the [Venom symbiote of that universe](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Venom_(Symbiote)_(Earth-96283)). That would make a degree of sense, since the two *Venom* films and the three Tobey Maguire *Spider-Man* films are all Sony Pictures productions. There's no specific indication that that's what they were going for though.

It could also be that there are symbiotes within the MCU/Sacred Timeline itself, and that one or more of them somehow know about the Tom Holland version of Peter. The possibility that it knew about the Tobey Maguire version, rather than the Tom Holland version, feels like less of a stretch to me, but these last two paragraphs are nothing more than speculation at this point.

Comment: The first implication is Venom seems to have multiverse knowledge because he recognizes Spider-Man and was just bragging about how much he knows.  I disagree with you - The second implication seems to be it was a coincidence they switched universes at that point. "SYMBIOTE: It wasn’t me."

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding here, because nothing in my answer is intended to suggest that the symbiote itself transported them across universes, or knew what was happening. What I'm suggesting is that the symbiote somehow had knowledge of Spider-Man and his secret identity, and that the sharing of this knowledge with Eddie made the both of them subject to Dr. Strange's spell.

Comment: I appear to have overreacted to to word "catalyst" in your original  text as I work with chemicals and catalysts cause things.  With a careful re-read you didn't actually say what I thought. Though obviously the movie needed to clarify it was not Venom doing it..  Given how connected Eddie and Venom are I doubt anyone would protest them being transported as a pair regardless of their conversation but in hindsight Venom has to be justifying his eligibility for transport  for the audience.

Comment: they take a lot of liberties with comics, but yes, why not

Comment: Suddenly, I feel like asking a question about what he actually meant when he said "80 billions light-years". Did they travel the equivalent of 80 billions years at the speed of light? That sounds like hell of a lot of distance.

Comment: @Clockwork yeah it doesn't make much sense. Could be an overlooked error by the film makers. Maybe it's meant to be just 80 billion years although that also has flows since the Big Bang was only 13.8 billion years ago.

Comment: @Clockwork - I took it to mean that the symbiote hive mind has knowledge spanning 80 billion light years worth of space (i.e. members of their species have been to a lot of different planets across multiple universes).

Comment: @Clockwork The universe is around 90 billion light years big despite being 14 billion years old.  Most of that is unobservable because the Expansion is growing faster than the light is.  Expansion goes in both directions at an oversimplification but see https://youtu.be/vIJTwYOZrGU

Answer (score 6):

Both the characters of Venom and Eddie Brock, Jr. know Peter Parker’s identity.

In *Spider-Man 3*, Venom in fact was Parker’s symbiote first before Parker rid himself of Venom before it attached to Brock.

These events were seen in *Spider-Man 3*, which are part of the MCU’s “multiverse.”

It is not yet known how Doctor Strange’s spell interacts with these other versions of the same characters, but at least one Venom and one Eddie Brock, Jr. in the MCU multiverse know Parker’s identity; these characters come from the same alternate universe within the MCU which includes other characters of the same universe who have interacted with MCU’s Spider-man, including that universe’s own Spider-man whom that universe’s Venom/Eddie Brock know the identity of.

Answer (score 4):

Since the characters pulled across space by Strange's spell were also pulled across *time*, this means that there is the **possibility** of Eddie Brock knowing Spider-Man's identity later on in his movies. Or he could have found out, or it could have been the symbiote Venom itself that knew; **we're unsure as of right now, but it is likely to be answered later on if the characters from other Sony titles return to the MCU.**

Answer (score 4):

The film's co-writer spoke about this in an interview. In short, all of the venoms in the multiverse share a common intellect, if only on a subconscious level.

> Brock was ultimately relegated to the “No Way Home” post-credits scene instead. As for how a character who had never met any Peter Parker, let alone Spider-Man, could be pulled into the MCU by a spell specifically drawing people who had to know Peter Parker was Spider-Man?
>
> “The idea is that the symbiote has knowledge of other universes. Buried in his brain is some knowledge of that connection,” McKenna said.
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Spider-Man: No Way Home’ Screenwriters Explain All Those Surprises and Spoilers: ‘This Wasn’t Just Fan Service’](https://variety.com/2021/film/news/spider-man-no-way-home-spoilers-tobey-maguire-andrew-garfield-aunt-may-1235144617/)</sup></sub>